# Load the same page between two webviews once?

Tags: android, xamarin, video-streaming, android-webview

I am loading the same MJPG stream in a thumbnail webview and a fullscreen webview so that when you click on the thumbnail, it shows the fullscreen quickly. Right now, I load it once for the thumbnail and then when the user clicks the thumbnail, it loads it again for the fullscreen view. The problem is that this takes a few seconds and isn't acceptable.

So the question is how can I share the same loaded data between two webviews so the fullscreen webview loads nearly instantly?

Here is the code that I am using right now to make a thumbnail fullscreen:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.Webkit;

namespace TestApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "TestApp", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/Theme.DesignDemo")]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {


        WebView webView, webViewFull;


        // Just sample images.....these will be video streams later
        String URL1 = "http://8-themes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/a1fc35e49c1d62c0210462d6ae613b0d-320x240.jpg";


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
            webView.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
            webView.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;

            webView.LoadUrl(URL1);

            webViewFull = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webViewFull);
            webViewFull.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
            webViewFull.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;

            webView.Touch += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
                {
                     webViewFull.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                     cameraSettingsButton.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                     webViewFull.LoadUrl(URL1);
                     webView.RequestLayout();
                }
            };
         }
     }
 }
```

The layout file:

```
<AbsoluteLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/camera_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:rowCount="10"
            android:columnCount="5"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_y="400dp">
            <android.webkit.WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="240dp" />
        </GridLayout>
        <android.webkit.WebView
            android:id="@+id/webViewFull"
            android:layout_x="0dp"
            android:layout_y="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

I am just learning Xamarin, so any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT Posted it now. Let me know if there is a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do. Thanks!